# Blackberry 10 Cascade: reading sms from device

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I want to read SMS from device for this I use the following code..

```
using namespace bb::pim::message;
MessageService service;

MessageSearchFilter filter;
filter.addSearchCriteria(SearchFilterCriteria::Subject, "");
filter.addStatusCriteria(SearchStatusCriteria::Unread);
filter.setLimit(10);

QList<Message> localMessageResults = service.searchLocal(1, filter);
```

But I can't get any SMS list in result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing permission in your .bar file. See [link](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__pim__message__messageservice.html) for more information.

> Permissions: To use the messaging service, you must set the
>   access_pimdomain_messages permission to access email and PIN messages
>   and the access_sms_mms permission to access text messages. These
>   permissions are set in the bar-descriptor.xml file of your project.

Also this [sample app](http://blackberry.github.io/Cascades-Samples/messages.html) will help.